# How to ensure that child method is run when you have parent instances in PHP

Tags: php, inheritance, polymorphism

In this example, foreach will always output `'I am Vehicle'` and never `'I am Car'` or `'I am Bus'`.

How to achieve that I got output related to the type of class ?

So `Car` should output `'I am Car'`, `Bus` should output `'I am Bus'`, etc...

```
class Vehicle {
    public function getName(){
        return 'I am Vehicle';
    }
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    public function getName(){
        return 'I am Car';
    }
}

class Bus extends Vehicle {
    public function getName(){
        return 'I am Bus';
    }
}

$vehicles = fetchAllVehicles();

foreach( $vehicles as $v){
    echo $v->getName();
}
```

Comment: Fetch all vehicles seems to return vehicle objects , not cars or buses. You have to instantiate the right subclass and that'll work.

Comment: Then it's easier to define attribute `type` and have only one getName() in Parent class which check the `type` and return the value... but why then OOP :-) ?

Comment: If you have no control of object instantiation, then that would work.